# Controlling one page scroll with correct navigation link activation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a one page website. You can view the website [here.](http://www.fantasylab.no/comingsoon)

The problem is, if you for example click "Om FantasyLab" in the top navigation, the "Referanser" link gets activated. IT shouldn't be like this, but for some reason it gets activated.

Also how can I make the one page scrolling stop where the background starts? Currently it stops at the `h1` tags

Here is the full HTML code:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#myScrollspy" style="margin-top: 0">

<header id="hjem">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="myScrollspy">
        <div class="container-fluid" style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #101b49;"  >
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="Hjem" href="#hjem" title="FantasyLab">
                <img src="images/fantasylab-logo.svg" style="width: 160px; margin-top: 5px;">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- navbar-header -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#om-fantasylab">Om FantasyLab</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#referanser">Referanser</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#lansering">Lansering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="social pull-right" style="margin: 25px 140px 0 0">
                    <a href="#" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter  fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Google Plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus  fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="YouTube"><i class="fa fa-youtube  fa-2x"></i></a>
                </div> 
                 <a href="form.html" class="header-button btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right" role="button">Bli kunde</a>
            </div> <!-- navbar-collapse -->
        </div> <!-- container -->
    </nav> 
</header> <!-- header -->

<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
           <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                    <h1 style="text-shadow: 0 0 10px #0089ea;">Vi er<br><strong>under utvikling.</strong></h1>
                   <p style="text-shadow: 0 0 10px #0089ea;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur loremsit amet consectetur lorem.</p>
                   <p style="text-shadow: 0 0 10px #0089ea;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur loremsit.</p>
                   <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Om FantasyLab</a>
               </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
           </div> <!--carousel-caption -->
        </div> <!--item active -->
    </div> <!-- carousel-inner -->
            <a href="#om-fantasylab">
                <div class="numberCircle center-block">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
            </a>
</div> <!-- myCarousel -->

<div class="om-fantasylab container-fluid" id="om-fantasylab">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase">Lorem ipsum<br><span style="color: #e0349a;"><strong>dolor sit amet cons.</strong></span></h1>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2 class="text-uppercase" style="color: #e0349a;">Hvem vi er</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum er rett og slett dummytekst fra og for trykkeindustrien. Lorem Ipsum har vært bransjens standard for tekst. Ny tekst kommer snart. Lorem Ipsum har vært bransjens standard for tekst. </p>
        </div> <!-- col-md-3 -->
        <div class="col-md-3" >
            <h2 class="text-uppercase" style="color: #e0349a;">Hva vi gjør</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum er rett og slett dummytekst fra og for trykkeindustrien. Lorem Ipsum har vært bransjens standard for tekst. Ny tekst kommer snart. Lorem Ipsum har vært bransjens standard for tekst. </p>
        </div> <!-- col-md-3 -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2 class="text-uppercase" style="color: #e0349a;">Hvordan vi jobber</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum er rett og slett dummytekst fra og for trykkeindustrien. Lorem Ipsum har vært bransjens standard for tekst. Ny tekst kommer snart. Lorem Ipsum har vært bransjens standard for tekst. </p>
        </div> <!-- col-md-3 -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2 class="text-uppercase" style="color: #e0349a;">hvorfor vi gjør det</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum er rett og slett dummytekst fra og for trykkeindustrien. Lorem Ipsum har vært bransjens standard for tekst. Ny tekst kommer snart. Lorem Ipsum har vært bransjens standard for tekst. </p>
        </div> <!-- col-md-3 -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- om-fantasylab -->

<div class="referanser container-fluid" id="referanser">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase text-center" style="margin: 80px 0; text-transform: none; color:#3c4761">Våre fornøyde <span style="color: #3c4761;"><strong>klienter.</strong></span></h1>
        <div class="referanser-content col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <a href="http://www.comcare.no" target="_blank" alt="ComCare Solutions">
                <img src="images/referanser-bilde.jpg">
                <div class="content-referanser">
                    <blockquote>
                      <h2 class="text-uppercase" style="color: #3c4761;">ComCare Solutions AS</h2>
                      <p><i>"Takk FantasyLab for et kjempe fint samarbeid. Dere har vært kreative, lyttende og virkelig sett meg under hele prosessen. Dere så mine behov og skapte en hjemmeside som har alle de tingene jeg ønsker. Er meget fornøyd å gir dere de beste anbefalinger videre."</i></p>
                      <footer>Aina Kise, Dagligleder - <cite title="Source Title">ComCare Solutions AS </cite></footer>
                    </blockquote>
                </div> <!-- content-referanser -->
            </a>
        </div> <!-- col-md-6 -->

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <a href="http://www.topphelse.net" target="_blank" alt="Topp Helse">
                <img src="images/topp-helse.jpg">
                <div class="content-referanser">
                    <blockquote>
                      <h2 class="text-uppercase" style="color: #3c4761;">Topp Helse</h2>
                      <p><i>"Takk FantasyLab for et kjempe fint samarbeid. Dere har vært kreative, lyttende og virkelig sett meg under hele prosessen. Dere så mine behov og skapte en hjemmeside som har alle de tingene jeg ønsker. Er meget fornøyd å gir dere de beste anbefalinger videre."</i></p>
                      <footer>Nicolinn Dixon, Dagligleder - <cite title="Source Title">Topp Helse</cite></footer>
                    </blockquote>
                </div> <!-- content-referanser -->
            </a>
        </div> <!-- col-md-6 -->


    </div> <!-- row -->


        <div class="row" style="margin: 160px 0 40px 0; padding: 0 80px;">
            <h3 class="pull-left" style="margin-top: 30px; font-weight: 400;">Ønsker du å <span style="color: #6c56bf; font-weight:700;">bestille en webløsning?</span> Vi ser frem til en hyggelig prat!</h3>
                <a class="kontakt-knapp btn pull-right" href="#kontakt" role="button">Kontakt oss</a>
                <a class="bestill-knapp btn pull-right" href="#" role="button">Bestill webløsning</a>
        </div>
</div> <!-- referanser -->  

<div class="lansering container-fluid" id="lansering">
    <div class="row" style=" margin: 0 60px;">
        <img class="center-block" src="images/lansering.png" style="width: 200px; margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >
            <h1 class="text-uppercase text-center" style="color: #fff;">Vi lanserer <span style="color:#00b4a2;"><strong>snart.</strong></span></h1>
            <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 18px; color:#fff;">Vi er rett rundt hjørnet! I mellomtiden, meld deg på vår nyhetsbrev for informasjon rundt lansering, kampanjer og nyheter innenfor informasjonsteknologi verdenen.</p>
            <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                <form action="//fantasylab.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d1f6a8e82535d2fcc14bfa66f&amp;id=36a4ce5a35" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Din e-postadresse" required>
                    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Meld deg på nyhetsbrev" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
                </form>
                <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            </div> <!-- mc_embed_signup -->
        </div> <!-- col-md-6 -->
    <img class="light" src="images/light.png">
    </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- lansering -->               

<div class="kontakt container-fluid" id="kontakt">
    <div class="row" style=" margin: 0 60px;">
            <h1 class="text-uppercase text-center" style="color: #fff;">Ta kontakt <span style="color:#0089ea;"><strong>med oss</strong></span></h1>
            <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 18px; color:#fff;">Våre utviklere ser frem til å høre om dine behov.</p>           
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="well well-sm">
          <form class="form-horizontal" action="index.php" method="post">
          <fieldset>

            <!-- Name input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="cname" name="cname" type="text" placeholder="Firmanavn" class="form-control"> 
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Name input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Kontaktperson" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Email input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Din e-postadresse" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" id="budsjett">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="budsjett">Ditt budsjett</label>
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                    kr 5.000 - 15.000

                  </label>
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                    kr 15.000 - 50.000
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                    kr 50.000 +
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                    N/A
                  </label>
                </div>                      
            </div>


            <!-- Message body -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Vennligst skriv inn melding..." rows="5"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Form actions -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="kontakt-send btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send melding</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

                            <img class="light" src="images/light.png">
    </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- kontakt -->

<footer>
    <div class="footer container-fluid">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                    <li><a href="#">Hjem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Om FantasyLab</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Referanser</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lansering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="form.html">Bli kunde</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="social center-block">
                    <a href="#" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter  fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Google Plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus  fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="YouTube"><i class="fa fa-youtube  fa-2x"></i></a>
                </div> 
                <p class="text-center" style="margin-top: 10px;">Copyright &copy; 2015 FantasyLab DA. NO 914 798 493.<span style="color:#5a68a2;"> Utviklet med <i alt="kjærlighet" class="fa fa-heart" style="color:#e17cb7;"></i> i Oslo, Norge.</span></p>               

            </div> <!-- col-md-12 -->
            <!--<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
            <div class="g-follow" data-annotation="bubble" data-height="20" data-href="//plus.google.com/u/0/113341766920062371221" data-rel="publisher"></div>
            -->
        </div> <!-- text-center -->
    </div> <!-- footer container -->
</footer> <!-- footer -->   

</body>  <!-- body -->
```

Is there any way I can fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This web page uses anchors to navigate and not javascript or jquery scroller. Check [animatescroll plugin](http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/#)....  Add it to your website and there you go

Give every link of yours id like `<a href="#" id="button1">Om Fantasylab</a>` then create your own little jquery script like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {

   $('#button1').click(function(){
       $('#om-fantasylab').animatescroll();
   });

   .. same with rest of your buttons ..

});
```

Save it in file like buttonHandler.js somewhere and add it to your page after Jquery and animate scroll scripts:

```
<script src="buttonHandler.js"> </script>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! Do you know how I can make the clicked link activated or highlighted with this plugin?

Comment: What code do you use for button click event atm ?

Comment: I currently use `.animatescroll();`

Comment: <a onclick="$('[jquery selector]').animatescroll([options]);">Go to Element</a>  ?  this example ? Please update your question and post your code or at least part with onclick event there.

Comment: Umm..

Here is the full code:

<a href="#" onclick="$('#om-fantasylab').animatescroll();">Om Fantasylab</a>

Comment: Hmm, i think you maybe misunderstood my question. Currently when you click a link for example: "Om FantasyLab" it scrolls down to that section, that's okay, but the link itself doesn't stay activated or highlighted

Comment: If you go to the website, you can see that, upon scroll the links also gets activated depending on which section you are on.

I wanted to achieve that with AnimateScroll plugin, is that possible?